# Member Relationship

Tags: members, relationships

I have been trying to figure this out and I can't seem to figure out an approach. This seems like something that should be a part of ExpressionEngine? I really don't want to have to use an add-on for this.

All I want to do is have a channel related to members. So if a member creates a "Guild" I can say "Give me all guild's for this member". Also, if I create a "Character" that belongs to a member and a guild... I would like to be able to say "Give me all characters for my member".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The last time I worked with EE was EE2 lol. This is on EE 6.

Answer (score 0):

If the entries are all authored by the member, you can use the author_id param, along the following lines, in your channel entries l

author_id="CURRENT_USER"

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/entries.html#author_id